Analytical Solution for a 2D Recurrence Relation
How can I analytically solve the following 2D recurrence relation?
$$
f(n,m) = \frac{n}{n+m}f(n-1, m+1) + \frac{m}{n+m}f(n, m-1) + 1
$$
with the boundary conditions:
$$
f(0,m) = 0
$$
$$
f(n, 0) = f(n-1, 1) + 1
$$
I can efficiently obtain a fractional expression using Mathematica with recursion and memoization:
f[0, m_] := f[0, m] = 0
f[n_, 0] := f[n, 0] = f[n - 1, 1] + 1
f[n_, m_] := f[n, m] = n/(n + m) f[n - 1, m + 1] + m/(n + m) f[n, m - 1] + 1

However, this was a math interview question I recently encountered, where the interviewer expected me to derive a fractional expression for  $f(4, 8) = \frac{739}{60}$ in under two minutes, using only paper and pen—no coding allowed. If I were to use the given recursion and manually compute $f(n, m)$ for $1 \leq n \leq 4$ and $0 \leq m \leq 8$ through dynamic programming, I would need to carefully calculate $36=4\times9$ states, involving fractional additions and multiplications. How could anyone complete this by hand in just 120 seconds, especially considering that those 120 seconds also include the time needed to understand the question and formulate the mathematical abstraction? Therefore I gauss there should be an analytical solution to this recursion.
The original question is:
A box contains 4 identical large balls and 8 identical small balls. Each minute, Alex randomly selects a ball from the box with equal probability. If a small ball is selected, it is removed; if a large ball is selected, it is replaced by a small ball, which is returned to the box. How many minutes are expected until the box contains only small balls?
PS:
I have derived the analytic solution:
$$f(n,m) = \frac{nm}{n+1} + 2n - H_n$$
where $H_n$ represents the $n$-th Harmonic Number. However, beyond verifying the correctness by substituting it back into the original formula, I am still unsure how to directly derive it from the original recurrence relation. I initially discovered this result by plotting $f(n, m)$ vs $m$ with a fixed $n$ and observing that it was linear. I noticed that the slope followed the pattern $\frac{n}{n+1}$. By enumerating $f(n, 0)$, I also found that $f(n, 0) - f(n-1, 0) = 2 - \frac{1}{n}$.

For the DP, you would need to calculate even more than $36$ states because you also need $f(1,9), f(1,10), f(1,11), f(2,9), f(2,10), f(3,9)$.

@RobPratt Yes, You're right. I just give a rough estimation of the task complexity. Then I gave up using brute force computation.
